Is Andromeda tilted up or down relative to us?
Here's a typical photo of the Andromeda galaxy.
It is hard to see whether we are peering down on its topside or up at its underside relative to us.  As an example of what I mean, in the following illusion the figure spins in different directions depending on whether perceived viewing angle is from above or from below.

Is the top left edge of the galaxy in the image closer to us, or farther from us, than the lower right edge?

What do you mean by "top".  Galaxies have no natural direction that is "up".  I think you mean, which part of the galaxy is closest too us,  the side with M32 or the side  with M119

@James K Rotating galaxies do have a distinction between the positive and negative directions of their angular momentum vector (their “north” and “south” poles, as it were).

But "positive" and "negative" are arbitrary labels, there still isn't an "up"

Thanks for the comments.  I've edited the question to clarify what I'm asking.

To me, it has always been pretty obvious the bottom right edge is closer.  The dust lane there is dark compared to the dust lanes on the other side, indicating the top left lanes have many more stars obscuring them.
